# Pandas: For every row in df calculate number of times that value exist in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data frame.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'selected': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D'], 'presented': ['A|B|D', 'B|D|A', 'A|B|C', 'D|C|B|A','A|C|D|B', 'D|B|C','D|C|B|A','D|B|C']})
>>> df
```

This is a large data set and have 500K rows (date column taken out to keep example simple)

```
  selected presented
0        A     A|B|D
1        B     B|D|A
2        C     A|B|C
3        A   D|C|B|A
4        B   A|C|D|B
5        C     D|B|C
6        A   D|C|B|A
7        D     D|B|C
```

Goal is to calculate `selected/presented` ratio for each item in the selected column. Example `A` was presented in `8` times but it was only selected `6` times out of those `8` times it was presented to the user.

I would like to create following resulting data.frame:

```
item, selected, presented, ratio
A, 3, 6, 0.5
B, 2, 8, 0.25
```

I started with following but can't figure out the grouping because if I just group by `selected` and start counting it would only capture the time it was shown.

```
>>> df['ratio'] = df.apply(lambda x:1 if x.selected in x.presented.split('|') else 0, axis=1)
>>> df
  selected presented  ratio
0        A     A|B|D      1
1        B     B|D|A      1
2        C     A|B|C      1
3        A   D|C|B|A      1
4        B   A|C|D|B      1
5        C     D|B|C      1
6        A   D|C|B|A      1
7        D     D|B|C      1
```

Comment: `A` seems to be presented 6 times and selected 3 times, unless my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

You can using `get_dummies` + `value_counts`, then `concat` the result

```
s1=df.presented.str.get_dummies('|').sum().to_frame('presented')
s2=df.selected.value_counts()
yourdf=pd.concat([s1,s2],1,sort=True)
yourdf['ratio']=yourdf['selected']/yourdf['presented']

yourdf
Out[488]: 
   presented  selected     ratio
A          6         3  0.500000
B          8         2  0.250000
C          6         2  0.333333
D          7         1  0.142857
```

Comment: @add-semi-colons split your df and do it chunk by chunk will be the best way :-)

Comment: I am geting ratio for every item in the presented column, if we have 20 items presented for each presented item and only 4 items are click this going to cost right?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'selected': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'D'], 'presented': ['A|B|D|E|R|K', 'B|D|A|K|L|M', 'A|B|C', 'D|C|B|A|F|Q','A|C|D|B|Q', 'Q|D|B|C','G|D|C|B|A','M|D|B|C']})` can we only create the ratio that are selected but not every split item in the presented column?

Comment: @add-semi-colons it will raise the cost of memory

Answer (score 2):

How about this one-liner:

```
df['presented'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().value_counts(sort=False).to_frame('presented')\
               .assign(selected = df['selected'].value_counts())\
               .eval('ratio = selected / presented')
```

Output:

```
   presented  selected     ratio
A          6         3  0.500000
C          6         2  0.333333
B          8         2  0.250000
D          7         1  0.142857
```

Comment: You'll need to run timeit.  I suspect that using get_dummies is better than stack.  @Wen-Ben solution should be faster than this one.